# What is the cause of a "MetadataAccessException" when parsing an Identity Token?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

In our production environment, we are receiving a `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Auth.Validation.MetadataAccessException` when validating an Identity Token for one particular user.

The validation code is:

```
var token = (AppIdentityToken)AuthToken.Parse(rawToken);
token.Validate(new Uri(hostUri));
```

This happens only for one particular user, and the validation has successfully completed a few times. The majority of the time it fails with the full message:

> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Auth.Validation.MetadataAccessException:
>   The Metadocument could not be retrieved. The remote server returned an
>   error: (500) Internal Server Error

Has anyone seen this exception before?

Answer (score 0):

The exception message seems pretty descriptive to me.  The `Validate` method calls a remote server to retrieve a metadata document, and is getting a 500 error from the server. That is the cause of the exception.

The URL that is called is embedded in the `appctx.amurl` field within the token payload, as shown in the following sample taken from [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/inside-the-identity-token#identity-token-payload):

```
{ 
  "aud": "https://mailhost.contoso.com/IdentityTest.html", 
  "iss": "00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000@mailhost.contoso.com", 
  "nbf": "1331579055", 
  "exp": "1331607855", 
  "appctxsender": "00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000@mailhost.context.com",
  "isbrowserhostedapp": "true",
  "appctx": { 
    "msexchuid": "53e925fa-76ba-45e1-be0f-4ef08b59d389@mailhost.contoso.com",
    "version": "ExIdTok.V1",
    "amurl": "https://mailhost.contoso.com:443/autodiscover/metadata/json/1"
  } 
}
```

In the example, you can see the `amurl` field, which is what is called during `Validate`.  The process of validation is described even further [in this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/validate-an-identity-token), including retrieving the metadata document in the third step.

The real question is, what is the cause of the 500 error when trying to retrieve the metatdata document?  This would likely be found in some server-side logs.  Just a guess, but since you said it succeeds sometimes, maybe the problem has to do with the load placed on the server.  You would need to investigate further to find out.

As to "Has anyone seen this exception before?" Not me - but I'm sure the answer is Yes. ;)

Comment: The `Validate` method does not call the remote server specified by the `hostUri`. The `hostUri` in the validate call is to [validate the jwt audience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43000774/audience-uri-validation-failed-audience-does-not-match). I think the exception is thrown by the exchange server, to which I do not have access. Maybe there is an exchange server configuration that would cause this? I don't know.

Comment: Thanks, I did some more research and updated my answer accordingly.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Investigating the jwt I can see the amurl points to a mail server hosted by the client. I will work with them to try and find information in their error logs. Thank you.